# limit() function execution order in Gremlin?

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop, tinkerpop3, azure-cosmosdb-gremlinapi

I have encountered a problem when using Gremlin. Vertex JobDefinition1 has edges named JobDefinitionToJobHistory, and the target of these edges are the job history vertices. In 2022-02-12, JobDefinition1 has two job history vertices, the first status of job history vertex is failed and the second status of job history vertex is succeed.

So, when I execute the Gremlin query below, I get the expected result which is a vertex with a succeed status(2 means succeed).

```java
g.V("JobDefinition1").out('JobDefinitionToJobHistory').has("ExecutionStartTime", between("2022-02-12T00:00:00Z", "2022-02-13T00:00:00Z")).order().by('ExecutionStartTime', decr).limit(1)
```

But when I execute the Gremlin query below, I get the incomprehensible result which is a vertex with a failed status (1 means failed). The expected result of this query I think should be empty or null.

```java
g.V("JobDefinition1").out('JobDefinitionToJobHistory').has("ExecutionStartTime", between("2022-02-12T00:00:00Z", "2022-02-13T00:00:00Z")).order().by('ExecutionStartTime', decr).limit(1).has("Status", 1)
```

I am very confused about the second Gremlin query result. Is the execution order of the `limit` function different from what we believe? Or is this result is caused by other reasons I don't know about? Hope you can give me some advice, Thanks!

Comment: what graph database are you using?

Comment: hi @stephenmallette, I use azure cosmos graph db.

Comment: this may be an issue particular to cosmosdb then. i dont seem to be able to recreate this problem in TinkerGraph and dont see any core optimizations that would be incorrectly applied to produce this issue.

Comment: If the behaviour is due to a too aggressive optimization by CosmosDb, you can try and prevent it by putting the steps before the final has() step inside an enclosing local() step.